# обработка исключений триггеров sqlite в коде программы на java

Tags: java, sqlite

есть триггер

```
sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TRIGGER " + TRIGGER_INSERT_NAME
            + " BEFORE INSERT ON " + STUDENTS_TABLE_NAME
            + " WHEN (SELECT count(*) FROM " + STUDENTS_TABLE_NAME
            + " WHERE " + STUDENTS_COLUMN_GROUP_ID + " = NEW." + STUDENTS_COLUMN_GROUP_ID
            + ") > 5 "
            + "BEGIN "
            + "SELECT RAISE (ABORT, 'Six items are already inserted.'); "
            + "END"
    );
```

код добавления

```
try {
            val = db.insert(STUDENTS_TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
            Log.d("QWERTT", "QWE" + val);
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            Log.e("DATAEERROR", e.toString());
        }
```

в val, при добавлении 6 записи будет -1, в android studio консоль исключение показывает, но try catch ничего не ловит

Comment: `в android studio консоль исключение показывает` какое?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

при вставке нужно пользоваться **insertOrThrow** , ловить исключение нужно **SQLiteConstraintException**

```
try {
    db.insertOrThrow(STUDENTS_TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
}
catch (SQLiteConstraintExceptione e)
{
    Log.e("TriggerERROR", e.toString());
}
```